# Is this deep obfuscation? Cannot understand the meaning of it

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Given the following script:

```js
É = -~-~[], ó = -~É, Ë = É << É, þ = Ë + ~[];
Ì = (ó - ó)[Û = ('' + {})[É + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + ([].ó + '')[ó - É] + (!!'' + '')[ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[É] + ('' + {})[É + ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó - É]][Û];
Ì(Ì((!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - ó] + (!'' + '')[É] + ((!'' + ''))[ó - É] + ([].$ + '')[ó - É] + '\'' + '' + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó - ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\'')())()
```

Which apparently looks obfuscated (at least to me), should eventually return more or less this:

```
return '\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\14 5\40\160\141\163 \163\145\47\51\73\ 151\146\50\141\7S\7S\47\164\157\164\1S7\61\62\63\154\1S7\1S4\47\S1\173\141\1S4\14S\162\164\50\47 \ 142\ 162\ 141\ 166\ 157\47\51\ 73\ 175\ 145\ 1 S4\ 163\ 145\ 173\ 141\ 154\ 145\ 162\ 164\50\47\ 146\ 141\ 1S1\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\ 175'
```

From here on we can unescape, however, how do I pass from the obfuscated to the escaped code?

I haven't found any online library which works for this type of deobfuscation. There used to be a [firefox extension](https://github.com/palant/jsdeobfuscator) which sadly is deprecated. The browser can parse and execute this code, so evidently it works. What I'm trying to do here is convert the script into something human-readable.

Comment: That would only work for one kind of obfuscation technique, quite likely from the one obfuscation service. What you're asking for is something that can detect obfuscation methods (or none), de-obfuscate, and assume you know what the decoded code does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward, just tedious. First unpack the top variable declarations:

```
É = -~-~[], ó = -~É, Ë = É << É, þ = Ë + ~[];
```

These variables resolve to the numbers `2`, `3`, and `7` respectively.

```
É = 2;
ó = 3;
þ = 7;
```

The next part:

```
Ì = (ó - ó)[Û = ('' + {})[É + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + ([].ó + '')[ó - É] + (!!'' + '')[ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[É] + ('' + {})[É + ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó - É]][Û];
```

is equivalent to

```
Û = ('' + {})[É + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + ([].ó + '')[ó - É] + (!!'' + '')[ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[É] + ('' + {})[É + ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó - É]
Ì = (ó - ó)[Û][Û];
```

Replace the variables with their values, and you get:

```
Û = ('' + {})[2 + 3] + ('' + {})[3 - 2] + ([][3] + '')[3 - 2] + (!!'' + '')[3] + ({} + '')[3 + 3] + (!'' + '')[3 - 2] + (!'' + '')[2] + ('' + {})[2 + 3] + ({} + '')[3 + 3] + ('' + {})[3 - 2] + (!'' + '')[3 - 2]
Ì = (3 - 3)[Û][Û];
```

Continually search and replace the addition and subtraction operators with what they evaluate to, eg search for `2 + 3` and replace with `5`:

```
Û = ('' + {})[5] + ('' + {})[1] + ([][3] + '')[1] + (!!'' + '')[3] + ({} + '')[6] + (!'' + '')[1] + (!'' + '')[2] + ('' + {})[5] + ({} + '')[6] + ('' + {})[1] + (!'' + '')[1]
```

There are a few techniques used to generate strings here:

```
('' + {})    -> '[object Object]'
(!!'' + '')  -> 'false'
(!'' + '')   -> 'true'
([][3] + '') -> 'undefined'
```

Put it all together:

```
Û = '[object Object]'[5] + '[object Object]'[1] + 'undefined'[1] + 'false'[3] + ({} + '')[6] + 'true'[1] + 'true'[2] + '[object Object]'[5] + ({} + '')[6] + '[object Object]'[1] + 'true'[1]
```

which evaluates to

```
Û = 'constructor'
```

so

```
Ì = (3 - 3)[Û][Û];
// evaluates to
Ì = (0).constructor.constructor;
// which is
Ì = Function
```

The final part evaluates to

```
Ì(Ì(< a bunch of stuff >)())()
```

Luckily, that "bunch of stuff" does not contain any assignment, or any statements at all - it is nothing more than a very long concatenated string, created using basic obfuscation techniques, but without using anything fancy, just like `Û` above. Use the same technique as with `Û`, and you get the string you posted in the question:

```
return'\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\145\40\160\141\163\163\145\47\51\73\151\146\50\141\75\75\47\164\157\164\157\61\62\63\154\157\154\47\51\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\142\162\141\166\157\47\51\73\175\145\154\163\145\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\146\141\151\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\175'
```

That's just a whole lot of character escapes. For example, `\141` is `a`, `\75` is `=`, `\160` is `p`, etc. Replace each with the appropriate character, and you get the string:

```
return'a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}'
```

Which gets passed to `Function` and gets executed. Try running the snippet below and pasting in `toto123lol`:

```js
É = -~-~[], ó = -~É, Ë = É << É, þ = Ë + ~[];
Ì = (ó - ó)[Û = ('' + {})[É + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + ([].ó + '')[ó - É] + (!!'' + '')[ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[É] + ('' + {})[É + ó] + ({} + '')[ó + ó] + ('' + {})[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó - É]][Û];
Ì(Ì((!'' + '')[ó - É] + (!'' + '')[ó] + (!'' + '')[ó - ó] + (!'' + '')[É] + ((!'' + ''))[ó - É] + ([].$ + '')[ó - É] + '\'' + '' + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó - ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (É + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (ó + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + É) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (É + ó) + (É + É) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó + ó) + '\\' + (É + É) + (þ) + '\\' + (É + ó) + (ó - É) + '\\' + (þ) + (ó) + '\\' + (ó - É) + (þ) + (É + ó) + '\'')())()
```

Whenever you have a string like `"return '\141\75\160\162\157\155\....`, the easiest way to transform it is to just paste it into a code editor and have it evaluate the escapes:

```js
const str = "return'\141\75\160\162\157\155\160\164\50\47\105\156\164\162\145\172\40\154\145\40\155\157\164\40\144\145\40\160\141\163\163\145\47\51\73\151\146\50\141\75\75\47\164\157\164\157\61\62\63\154\157\154\47\51\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\142\162\141\166\157\47\51\73\175\145\154\163\145\173\141\154\145\162\164\50\47\146\141\151\154\56\56\56\47\51\73\175'";

console.log(str);
```

Comment: way, way too much free time on your hands. +1.

Comment: Another way to break the code @Stavm is by deleting the last `()` of the anonymous function, eventually it provides clean javascript. I like your approach regarding the string generation technique, did you find and replaced them manually or is there some tool which can help automate the conversion to character escapes?

Comment: @AvaBarbilla I did it manually. There were only a few combinations to replace, so it was trivial